# How to represent many-to-many relastionship in ERD

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I am trying to build restaurant system.
First I am building ER diagram for the requirements.
I have two tables, customer, it has only attribute which is table_number, and
another table is Item, which is the dishes that the customer will choose from, and it has several attributes which are (id,name,category,price).
A part of requirements which I faced problem with it is :
when customer make the order and submit it, two things should be happened, first send the order details to the kitchen and then save the same order in history_order.
My question is :
how can i represent tow many-to-many relationship between these tables
I know how to represent the current order that will read it by chef, but i do not know
how to represent to kind of many-to-many relationship in the best way without break
the principles or best practices.
I downloaded my work in image to show you what i am talking about.
I hope it is clear and understandable.
If there is anything unclear, please just let me know by the comments.
[the ERD diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXUJ8.png)

Comment: Please identify the exact design method you are following & how you followed it & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck/unsure. (In ER & the relational model a relationship is between values and/or entities--not tables--& is represented by a table. In pseudo-ER a so-called "relationship between tables" is a FK constraint.)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: I used the picture because I can't express the problem I'm facing,
I have these entities : customer, items, order, history_orders
order has two attributes customer_table refer to customer_id into customer
and item_id refer to item_id into item entity 
when order is delivered it should be deleted,
but I don't want to do the same thing  to orders that are in history_order, how can I represent this in ER Diagram ?
The solution in my head consists duplication.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS "including tables & ERDs."--Everything in an ERD can easily be expressed in text.When such text is code it is called DDL. PS Please act on all of my 1st comment too. Otherwise you're asking to rewrite a textbook/tutorial, and for a method you don't identify, and without clearly explaining how you are stuck, ie in terms of following the method. And we can expect such a question to be a duplicate. [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score -1):

The order is the order.  It's sent to the kitchen, and it's archived in the history.  Like everything else, you want to record it *once*.  Possibly you'll refer to it from more than one table.

Let's say you have a table **order_items** with key attributes *order_id* and *item_id*.  Now you can look up all items for an order.  You could have another table to track the progress of each order.  Call it **orders** with attributes *order_id* and *status*, which might have values such as `ordered` (sent to kitchen), `ready` (to be served), `served`, perhaps `cancelled`, and (hopefully) `paid`.  You could also have an attribute *status_time* to record when the status was last updated.  Your list of orders "in the kitchen" are those orders with status `ordered`; the history is those with status `paid`.

You probably don't need an *order_id*.  From your description, it looks like *table_number* and *order_time* uniquely identify each order.  You could use that pair instead of an opaque ID.

Comment: Thank you for your response,I Appreciate it , but any way  I want to clarify something here ,
the purpose of history_order table is for making decisions by the manager,
when order delivered to the customer , the order will be deleted, but I need the order stay in the history_order
if I make a reference from history_order to order , when order is done and delivered to customer and deleted from order table, but it will be deleted from history_order also because of reference and i don't want it happen I just want to know how can i represent it in ER Diagram?

Comment: Will I break the principles of ER Diagram if I redundant the attributes of items and put it in history_order entity rather than use reference ? 
I don't want use reference to item or order because if any instance of them delete , the same instance will be deleted in history_order table too

Comment: The design I suggested doesn't require **history_order**.  That could be a view of **orders** with *status* `paid`, or something like that.  If someone says **orders** will get "too big" over time, ask for proof.  If proof is sufficient, you can archive "old" orders (last year, last month, whatever) to a history table while keeping "new history" in **orders**.  There really is no reason to keep the same information in the database more than once.